# Mass Contact Merge in Apex

Tags: dml, bestpractice, merge

I am trying to implement Mass merge of contacts in apex, Like uploading a CSV of multiple records which has would have details like retainable ID , duplicate contact Id etc., now I need to traverse over CSV and merge these records using Apex, but i see that we can only merge one master record with multiple duplicates, so to achieve my requirement I have to do merge DML in for loop.
Can some one let me know if we can achieve the same in a better way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no bulkified merge operation; Meghesh's answer is reasonable or you could use chained queueables or publish Platform events for each row with a subscriber configured to accept no more than x records per transaction

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a flag over your case contact which would indicate that you had created the record very recently by uploading the data

2.Create Batch Apex which would only query the records based on the flag

3.For Large Data Volumes only Batch Apex is an viable option since the governor limits would reset for each transaction